# How to dissolve brass surrounded by aluminium?

Tags: acid-base, everyday-chemistry, solubility, alloy

I have a broken off brass needle stuck in a caste aluminum hole. (It’s the pilot mixture jet on a carburetor).

I was wondering if there was a chemical that would dissolve the brass while not reacting to the aluminium.

Previously I’ve tried:

- Using thermal expansion and contraction to loosen it.
- Attempting to poke it out.
- Using an air compressor to blow it out.

Comment: Concentrated nitric acid will dissolve common brasses, but not aluminum. But, even if it works well, it would be slow going for a needle in a small hole. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Not likely. Ammonium hydroxide will attack brass, but at high concentrations and not very fast. And worse, I don't easily find data for aluminium in concentrated $\ce{NH4OH}$, probably because it has poor resistance.

I think you are stuck with mechanical options. Simplest is another carb or subsection. Drilling it out is obvious. Strangely enough, I have bits down to possible 0.010 " diameter but I don't know where you would buy tiny drill bits; likely you will need a few. They use collets rather than chucks to hold them , so you also need a collet or two. Sounds like more expense than a carburetor.